# Почему не добавляется класс при наведении файла?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите почему не добавляется класс к моей форме?
При перетаскивании файла с ПК на **id="drop-zona"** к ней должен добавится класс **is-dragover**, как только файл попадает в эту зону.

По логике addEventListener у меня обрабатывает несколько событий и при любом из них должен добавить класс..
события

1. dragover — Событие происхоит, когда элемент перетаскивается сверху (over) цели перетаскивание.
2. dragenter — Событие происхоит, когда перетаскиваемый элемент попадает в цель перетаскивания (drop target).

Я видел подобные решения на jQuery но я делаю это на JS...
Я пытался решить это сам, но не смог.. 2 дня в трубу, прошу помощи.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper-form">
    <div id="drop-zona"></div>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="main-form">
        <div class="form-em">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="fg-mr" placeholder="Your name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="fg-btn">
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email">
                </div>
            </div>
            <textarea name="text" rows="5" placeholder="your message..."></textarea>
            <div class="form-group">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="fg-mr fg-clear" id="clear-form" type="reset" value="Clear form">
                <div class="fg-mr fg-wrap">
                    <input class="fg-mr fg-upload-none" type="file" name="myfile[]" id="myfile" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple />
                    <label id="upload-container" class="fg-upload" for="myfile">Load file<span class="fg-upload-drag"> or drag it here</span></label>
                </div>
                <button id="send-btn-form" class="fg-send button-f" type="submit" value="Send">Send message</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
let dropZona = document.getElementById("drop-zona");
    dropZona.addEventListener("dragenter dragleave dragover drop", e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    dropZona.addEventListener("dragover dragenter", function() {
        dropZona.classList.add("is-dragover");
    });
    dropZona.addEventListener("dragleave drop", function() {
        dropZona.classList.remove("is-dragover");
    });
    dropZona.addEventListener("drop", e => {
        e.dataTransfer.files;
    });
```

Comment: Первым аргументом для `addEventListener()` должна быть строка с именем ОДНОГО события, строки вроде `"dragenter dragleave dragover drop"` воспринимаются не как список или порядок событий, но как длинное имя одного странного несуществующего события.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty т.е. подобная запись возможна только на jQuery? А мне нужно каждое событие отдельно вынести? Как это показано в тех-же примерах на learn.javascript Или через forEach что-бы он каждое отработал?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, да. Попробовал ответить с одним из вариантов.

Comment: Я немного исправил ответ: предыдущий вариант был неэкономный для памяти, потому что без нужды создавал дубликаты обработчиков в цикле.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty Да спасибо большое теперь это работает! А то я думал, почему консоль начала материться на меня )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первым аргументом для `addEventListener()` должна быть строка с именем ОДНОГО события, строки вроде `"dragenter dragleave dragover drop"` воспринимаются не как список или порядок событий, но как длинное имя одного странного несуществующего события.

Если вы хотите как-то сгруппировать обработчики для нескольких событий и не повторять код, можно попробовать циклы:

```js
const dropZona = document.getElementById("drop-zona");

function enter(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  dropZona.classList.add("is-dragover");
}

function leave(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  dropZona.classList.remove("is-dragover");
}

for (const eventName of ["dragenter", "dragover"]) {
  dropZona.addEventListener(eventName, enter);
}

for (const eventName of ["dragleave", "drop"]) {
  dropZona.addEventListener(eventName, leave);
}

dropZona.addEventListener("drop", function (e) {
  e.dataTransfer.files;
});
```